# How to reset the page state in React Native with RTK Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rtk-query

I'm working on a React Native project that uses RTK Query to fetch dynamic products from the DB. I implemented Infinite scroll functionality using the merge, serializeQueryArgs, and forceRefetch methods as available in the docs. This works perfectly as it should. However, for dynamic screens, I find it difficult to have the page reset to 1 when the screen dynamically changes. Instead, the page state from the previous screen is passed to the URL param of the new screen. This means that, if the page number was 4 in the previous screen and I navigate to a new screen, the page is not reset to 1, instead 4 is passed to the URL params of the new screen. I have tried to solve this issue and I haven't been able to make a headway. I'd like someone to point me to what I'm doing wrong. This is what my RTK Query code looks like:

```js
getProductsBySubCategory: builder.query<
      ProductsResponsePayloadTwo,
      QueryParamsTypes
    >({
      query: ({ limit, page, category, subCategory }) => ({
        url: config.products.getByDynamicQuery,
        params: {
          limit,
          page,
          category,
          subcategory: subCategory,
        },
      }),
      transformResponse: (response: ProductsResponsePayloadTwo) => {
        const results = response.data.products.map((product) => ({
          ...product,
          id: product._id,
        }));

        return {
          data: { products: results, total: response.data.total },
        };
      },
      serializeQueryArgs: ({ endpointName, queryArgs }) => {
        return `${endpointName}-${queryArgs.category}-${queryArgs.subCategory}`;
      },
      merge(currentCacheData, responseData, otherArgs) {
        currentCacheData.data.products.push(...responseData.data.products);
      },
      forceRefetch({ currentArg, previousArg }) {
        return currentArg !== previousArg;
      },
    }),
```

And this is what the component that consumes the API response looks like:

```js
const SubCategoryScreen = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(20);

  const {
    params: { categoryTitle, subcategoryName },
  } = useRoute<HomeRouteStackProps<"SubCategories">>();

  const navigation = useNavigation<NavigationPropTypes<"Home">>();
  const productRef = useRef<FlatList>(null);

  const categoryURI = encodeURIComponent(categoryTitle);
  const subCategoryURI = encodeURIComponent(subcategoryName);

  const {
    isLoading: loadingProducts,
    data: productsData,
    error: productError,
    isFetching,
    currentData,
  } = useGetProductsBySubCategoryQuery({
    limit,
    page,
    category: categoryURI,
    subCategory: subCategoryURI,
  });

  const products = productsData?.data.products ?? [];

  const prevCategoryURI = useRef(categoryURI);
  const prevSubCategoryURI = useRef(subCategoryURI);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerShown: false,
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (productRef.current) {
      productRef.current.scrollToOffset({ offset: 0, animated: true });
    }
  }, [categoryURI, subCategoryURI]);

  useEffect(() => {  
    if (categoryURI !== prevCategoryURI.current) {
      console.log("Resetting page due to category change");
      setPage(1);
      prevCategoryURI.current = categoryURI;
    }
  
    if (subCategoryURI !== prevSubCategoryURI.current) {
      console.log("Resetting page due to subcategory change");
      setPage(1);
      prevSubCategoryURI.current = subCategoryURI;
    }
  }, [categoryURI, subCategoryURI]);

  return (
      /* JSX Elements */
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of experience in React, but I asked a friend for you and he replied: "You can use the usePrevious hook to store the previous value of the page number. Then, in the useEffect hook, you can check if the page number has changed. If it has, you can reset the page number to 1."

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const usePrevious = (value) => {
  const ref = useRef(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);

  return ref.current;
};

const App = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const prevPage = usePrevious(page);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Current Page: {page}</h1>
      <h2>Previous Page: {prevPage}</h2>
      <button onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}>Next Page</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: This usePrevious hook - is it a custom hook ? And if it is, is there a way he could reproduce it in a sandbox for me to see?

Comment: Yes, it is a custom hook.
I've edited my answer to include a code example.
But as I said, it's not mine, I asked my coworker for it, I have no idea if that solves your problem